# Regular expression separation of string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string in different groups but I have no experience in this task.
So I need a regular expression that in Java divides the original string in two groups

A sample of my text is:

> calcani k a l k a n i

I want t:

- Group 1: calcani
- Group 2: k a l k a n i        (or, if possible, kalkani)

Any idea of how to create this pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to say that you wish to split the string based on spaces that appear in the string

Comment: Not exactly, for the first part I need to extract the string before the space and compare with a different part of my project, then use the second.

Comment: If thats the requirement then the many answers below should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String x="calcani k a l k a n i";
    String []x1=x.split(" ",2);
    System.out.println(x1[0]);
    System.out.println(x1[1]);
```

**output**

```
calcani
k a l k a n i
```

if you want output like below

```
calcani
kalkani
```

then use

```
String x="calcani k a l k a n i";
        String []x1=x.split(" ",2);
        System.out.println(x1[0]);
        System.out.println(x1[1].toString().replace(" ", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why regex. Just implement this logic:

1. Search first space and take substring on left of the first space
2. Rest of the string on right of first space is your 2nd match, at that point if you want to remove all the spaces you can use:

   ```
   String repl = str.replace(" ", "");
   ```

Comment: I tried to implement a regex because I have a list of entries and I have to compare the first group and then report the second one.
My idea after the the split in groups was to use the replace to delete spaces.

Comment: @user2893821 see my answer,I have provided both the ways

Comment: @user2893821: You shouldn't use regex unless until it is necessary. IN this case you can just do `int spacePost = string.indexOf(' ');` to get the position of first space and then simple `string.substring` methods to get your both sub strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [second argument in the `String.split()` method](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/UsingsecondargumentintheStringsplitmethodtocontrolthemaximumnumberofsubstringsgeneratedbysplittingastring.htm) to control the maximum number of substrings generated by splitting a string:

```
String[] temp = "calcani k a l k a n i".split(" ", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get both the string as follow:

```
 String[] results = "calcani k a l k a n i".split(" ", 2);
//remove spaces from second group
 String secondGroup=result[1];
 secondGroup=secondGroup.replaceAll(" ","");
 System.out.println("result[0] ->"+result[0]);
 System.out.println("result[1] ->"+result[1]);
```

**OutPut**

```
result[0] ->calcani
result[1] ->kalkani
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    String[] results = "calcani k a l k a n i".split(" ", 2);
    System.out.println(results[0]);
    System.out.println(results[1].replace(" ", ""));
```